# non member += overloading in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
  int a;
  A() { a = 2;}
  A(int f) { a= f;}
  void print() { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
};

class B
{
  A a, at, at2;
  A& operator += (A& b)
  {
    a.a = a.a + b.a;
    return a;
  }
public:
  B(int a_, int at_, int at2_) : a(a_), at(at_), at2(at2_) {};
  void update ()
  {
    a += at;
  }
  void printAll() { a.print(); at.print();}
};

int main()
{
  B value ( 2, 3, 5);
  value.printAll();
  value.update();
  value.printAll();
}
```

The error is :

> temp.cpp:24:10: error: no match for 'operator+=' in '((B*)this)->B::a += ((B*)this)->B::at'

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your overload takes a left side of a `B`, not an `A`.

Comment: What's the confusion? You have patently not defined an `operator+=` for class `A`...

Answer (score 2):

The operator you are defining is `A & operator+=(B &, A & )`, not `A & operator+=(A &, A &)`. So you have defined how to add an `A` to a `B`, but not how to add an `A` to an `A`. Try this after the definition of `class A` but before that of `class B`:

```
A & operator+=(A & a1, const A & a2) { a1.a += a2.a; return a1; }
```

But this kind of operator is more natural to define as a member function.

Comment: But can I not let it just be a member of class B. Essentially A is a structure .

Comment: I can make this function a part of my namespace so i'll be fine but could i not do it inside class B ?

Comment: @user1576929, If it's a member of `B`, the left hand side must be a `B`. No exceptions.

Comment: No, if it is a member of `B`, then it implicitly defines how to operate on a `B`, not on an `A`. And you are doing `a += at`, which tries to increment `a`, which is an `A`, by `at`, which is also an `A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
A& B::operator += (A& b)
```

Means

```
A & operator+=(B &, A & )
```

You simply need to add `operator +=(const A&b)`  to class A

```
class A
{
//....
    A& operator += (const A& b)
    {
       a += b.a;
       return *this;
    }
//....
};
```

A non-member version is:

```
A & operator+=(A a1, const A & a2) { a1.a += a2.a; return a1; }
```

Comment: I agree that this is best done via a member function, but he asked for a non-member way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah, I can't edit A. It is a part of ROS. I don't want to touch that. B is my function and I want all the overloading to affect only objects of A in B.